# How do I validate if these Expressions are valid (All brackets paired - closed)?

Tags: java, string, char

Here is my third attempt, however the expected result is incorrect.

1st expression should print -Bracket is balanced.
2nd expression should print -Bracket is NOT balanced.

NOTE NEED TO USE - **charAt**  or **substring to solve**, Not Array OR Stack! As I yet to learn these!

```
import java.lang.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CheckBracketsPairs {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateExpresion("(4+4)");
    validateExpresion("(4+4)*1)");
  }

  public static void validateExpresion(String s) {

    // MY CODES BELOW
    int count = 0;
    String open = "(";
    String close = ")";

    for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++) {
      Character c = s.charAt(i);

      if(c.equals(open)) {
        count++;
      }

      if(c.equals(close)) {
        count--;
      }
    }

      if(count == 0) {
        System.out.println("\n Expression:  " + s + ",      -Bracket is balanced");
      } else {
        System.out.println("\nBracket is NOT balanced");
      }
  }    
}
```

Comment: What the out put you are getting

Comment: A `Character`is never equal to a `String`

Comment: @GyroGearless Appreciate -- good to learn

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam   initial atempt, Outout showed both as -Bracket is balanced: Now fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another attempt here. Last line did not show result as expected. 
Should be -  **-Bracket is NOT balanced**

```
public class CheckBracketsPairs  {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateExpression(")((5+9)-2)");
    validateExpression("(2*6)-1)*(2^2)");
    validateExpression("(8^2)");
    validateExpression("(5+8^2))");  // This line computing?
    validateExpression("(5+8^2)(");  // Why is this line NOT computing?
  }

  public static void validateExpression(String s) {

    // MY CODES BELOW  
    int count = 0;
    char open = '(';
    char close = ')';

    for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++) {
      char c = s.charAt(i);

      if(c == open) {
        count++;
      }

      if (c == close) {
        count--;
        // If statement to check for closed brackets
        if (count < 0) {
          System.out.println("\nExpression:  " + s + "  -Bracket is NOT balanced");
          break;
        }
      }
    } 

    if (count == 0) {
      System.out.println("\nExpression:  " + s + "   -Bracket is balanced");
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: The last solution works for the most part, however fails in some expressions:    EXAMPLE:   validateExpresion(“(5+2) * 1) / (3-(2+1)”)               Although the brackets are even, they’re not closed. Expected Result should be       - Bracket is NOT balanced.

Comment: @MrCEO That is an issue with your logic though. You're testing ifthe number of open and close brackets are equal in your code *not* if they are closed. **Hint:** If your `count` variable is ever negative, you know you have an invalid case.

Comment: great hint, appreciate!  Will add second (if)condition and run the program again.

Comment: @MrCEO you should be checking if count < 0 right after your `count--;` line. Because what if count is < 0, then incremented back to 0? so : `if (count < 0) { System.out.println("not balanced"); break; }`

Comment: Very helpful tips, I have add the lines:   Using more test values ...Looking to understand why the last line is not computing (No result / output).

Comment: @MrCEO The last line *is* computing, but `count` never goes below 0, and finishes at `count = 1`, so you still need one final check at the end: `if (count > 0) { // not balanced }`

Comment: -- Absolutely perfect!  Phew! I've been trying every modification for hours. Highly appreciated.    Added accordingly: **if (count > 0) { // not balanced }**